# How to insert strings to all files in a directory using a terminal/Bash script

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a bunch of files.

```
AcademicCapIcon.svelte        ArrowSmLeftIcon.svelte        CalculatorIcon.svelte
AdjustmentsIcon.svelte        ArrowSmRightIcon.svelte       CalendarIcon.svelte
...
...
```

All files has the same format. For example `AcademicCapIcon.svelte` has the following:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
  <path d="M12 14l9-5-9-5-9 5 9 5z"/>
  <path d="M12 14l6.16-3.422a12.083 12.083 0 01.665 6.479A11.952 11.952 0 0012 20.055a11.952 11.952 0 00-6.824-2.998 12.078 12.078 0 01.665-6.479L12 14z"/>
  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 14l9-5-9-5-9 5 9 5zm0 0l6.16-3.422a12.083 12.083 0 01.665 6.479A11.952 11.952 0 0012 20.055a11.952 11.952 0 00-6.824-2.998 12.078 12.078 0 01.665-6.479L12 14zm-4 6v-7.5l4-2.222"/>
</svg>
```

I'd like to insert the following at the beginning of each file.

```
<script>
  export let className = "h-6 w-6";
</script>
```

And insert `class={className}` after `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`.

For example the final result of the above `AcademicCapIcon.svelte` file will be:

```
<script>
  export let className = "h-6 w-6";
</script>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class={className} fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
  <path d="M12 14l9-5-9-5-9 5 9 5z"/>
  <path d="M12 14l6.16-3.422a12.083 12.083 0 01.665 6.479A11.952 11.952 0 0012 20.055a11.952 11.952 0 00-6.824-2.998 12.078 12.078 0 01.665-6.479L12 14z"/>
  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 14l9-5-9-5-9 5 9 5zm0 0l6.16-3.422a12.083 12.083 0 01.665 6.479A11.952 11.952 0 0012 20.055a11.952 11.952 0 00-6.824-2.998 12.078 12.078 0 01.665-6.479L12 14zm-4 6v-7.5l4-2.222"/>
</svg>
```

How can I do this using a terminal or Bash script?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a small script to iterate through *.svelte files and apply sed to each of them:

```
for FILE in *.svelte; do
  sed -e '1i<script>\n  export let className = "h-6 w-6";\n</script>\n' -e 's/svg" fill/svg" class={className} fill/' $FILE >$FILE.new
done
```

the output files will be the original filename with .new extension, but if you're brave, add the -i option in the sed command and get rid of the >$FILE.new at the end

Comment: It didn't work. The file didn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Put the insert into a file of its own, and try

```
sed 's|xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"|& class={className}| ' insert_file orig_file
<script>
  export let className = "h-6 w-6";
</script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class={className} fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
.
.
.
</svg>
```